# What does δA mean in differentiation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, physics, partial-derivative

To be more specific, I met this when doing analytical mechanics involving the principle of least action:

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, $\delta A$ doesn't mean integration!

Comment: Yes, you're right this differentiation not integration. My mistake.

Comment: it's the total differential

Comment: What does the total differential mean?

Comment: They're definitions are similar.

Comment: Well, the author says it: $\delta A$ is the change in the function $A$ when its argument is varied a little bit.

Comment: Of course my comment is not to be taken seriously. This is standard physics language a physics book, and you rightfully ask how we can/should formalize this mathematically.

Comment: @Ali **Their** definitions.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff You're right. Egg on my face!(It's really late here, and I should be in my bed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to understand this notation is as follows:

- A **variation** is a transformation of the independent variables in a problem; it says that for each  $\epsilon$ we can transform $x_i$ to $x_i=x_i(\epsilon)=x_i + \epsilon\,\delta x_i + O(\epsilon^2)$ for some $\delta x_i$. You can think of it as a path in $\mathbf x$ space parametrized by $\epsilon$.
- Notice $$\left[\frac{\mathrm d x_i}{\mathrm d \epsilon}\right]_{\epsilon=0} = \delta x_i$$Thus the vector $\mathbf{\delta x}$ is a tangent to that path.
- In general, we define $$\delta F(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = \delta F(x_1(\epsilon),\cdots,x_n(\epsilon)) = \left[\frac{\mathrm d F}{\mathrm d \epsilon}\right]_{\epsilon=0}$$Hence $\epsilon\times \delta F$ is the **small change in $F$ under this variation**.
- Using the chain rule $$\delta F = \left[\frac{\mathrm d F}{\mathrm d \epsilon}\right]_{\epsilon=0} = \sum_i\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}\left[\frac{\mathrm d x_i}{\mathrm d \epsilon}\right]_0 = \sum_i\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}\delta x_i$$

This can be formalized using differential forms, but this above is key to a more intuitive understanding. The message is that $\delta F$ is the small change in $F$ due to the small change in $\delta \mathbf x$ in $\mathbf x$.

---

For completeness, we can very quickly sketch how one moves towards differential forms.

**Idea**: What derivatives $F'(x)$ are for is telling you how to figure out what a small change in $F$ is given a small change in $x$. Define $\mathrm d F$ to be something mapping a change in $x$ to the change in $F$ to first order in the Taylor expansion. $\mathrm d F(U) = U \times \partial_x F$.

In more arbitrary settings, you are allowed to change $\mathbf x$, thinking of it as a set of coordinates, by moving along any path in $\mathbf x$ space. (Here, we're thinking of allowing any path. In general, we might be constrained to **manifolds** like the unit sphere.) Then a small change along a path is determined by derivatives along that path; this is simply the tangent vector dotted with the gradient, $\mathbf U \cdot \nabla F$. In analogy with the above, we define
$$\mathrm d F(\mathbf U) = \text{derivative of $F$ along curve tangent to $\mathbf U$} = U_i \cdot \partial F/\partial x_i$$
using the chain rule for the last step.

This is essentially the idea of (exact) differential 1-forms: they take vectors to the derivatives of functions.

Comment: I think that I'm lost. Can you recommend a good book to start with from the beginning?

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid not! I've never really used books at undergrad level. If you can describe what about the above is difficult to understand perhaps I can clarify it.

Comment: I've added a little more explanation, including how it's formalized in terms of differential forms.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, the author is using $\delta$ for the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative), which is usually denoted $\operatorname{d}$.

The function $A$ is a function of several variables, say $A(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. The [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) of $A$ with respect to any one of the variables is denoted by
$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial x_i}$$
where $1 \le i \le n$. By definition, the exterior derivative of the [differential $0$-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Concept), i.e. of the function, $A$ is
$$\operatorname{d}\!A = \frac{\partial A}{\partial x_1}\, \operatorname{d}\!x_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial A}{\partial x_n}\, \operatorname{d}\!x_n$$

Each of the $\operatorname{d}\!x_i$ are [differential 1-forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form#Concept). They take a tangent vector and give the $i$-th component of that vector. If you want to get very technical then each of the $\operatorname{d}\!x_i$ are linearly independent covectors. Since each of the $\operatorname{d}\!x_i$ are linearly independent, $\operatorname{d}\!A = 0$ if and only if each of the partial derivatives are zero.

Comment: I don't know what an exterior derivative and a differential form is? What's dA?

Comment: @MohamedAyman That's why I added links when I wrote my answer. The words in blue are hyperlinks. If you click on the blue words you will be re-directed to the appropriate websites which will give you explanations.

Comment: Yes, I know. But the problem is that I don't what a differential of a function is to start with? I think I've missed something because I thought that the differential is the same as the derivative.

Comment: I gave the definition of the differential of a function:
$$\operatorname{d}\!A = \frac{\partial A}{\partial x_1}\,\operatorname{d}\!x_1 + \cdots + \frac{\partial A}{\partial x_n}\,\operatorname{d}\!x_n.$$
As I said: the $\operatorname{d}\!x_i$ are 1-forms. Differential forms are well-known and there are thousands of books written on them. I suspect that the book you photocopied is too advanced for you. If you don't understand the book, or the explanations. Mathematical study takes years. I can't explain four years' worth of work in a 500 character post. Sorry.

Comment: It's pretty optimistic to expect someone reading what looks like a first text on partial derivatives to be familiar with differential forms; the book is likely introducing things in a very informal way. It's not that the book is "too advanced" but that using differential geometry for a formal understanding is.

Comment: Just to be clear the differential of a function is equal to the summation of the partial derivative of every variable times the differential of that variable. In which year in college is someone supposed to be taught?

Comment: There is no standard answer to "in which year...?" questions. I would be surprised if differential forms were introduced in what looks like a first course on partial derivatives, though. And yes, that's simply what the chain rule says.

Comment: Last thing, is there a difference between taking a differential and a derivative?

Comment: Yes. Differentials are things which take any change in all of the $x_i$ and tell you what the change in $A$ should be. Formally in our simple case, they are maps from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$. They are essentially *gradients*, or collections of partial derivatives. Derivatives take a specific path and tell you what the change along that path is; they are maps from $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Sharkos It's a matter of perspective. I personally feel that my answer is easier to understand than yours and that you are the more optimistic of us both. I'm sure you see it from the other side. Either way the OP doesn't understand what either of us have said. (When I was an undergraduate I used to get books that I didn't understand because they looked cool and I used to ask my professors what different symbols meant. I'm not saying that getting a too advanced book is a bad thing, we all do it. I'm just suggesting the OP take a step back.)

Comment: @MohamedAyman: In my experience, differential forms are nonrigourously introduced in a course on multivariable calculus/analysis (1st or 2nd year), and are rigourously taught in a course on manifolds (say the 3rd year: advanced undergraduates).

Comment: @FlybyNight - IMO your answer is easier to understand *once you understand differential forms*! That's what I was driving at. Indeed, apparently we were both too unclear. I definitely think that this is a topic usually introduced informally first. I do **not** think the book is trying to introduce differential forms except by accident.

Comment: @FlybyNight You're right I should take a step back and concentrate more on the more elementary stuff.

Comment: @Sharkos This book is called The Theoretical Minimum it's a physics book that had a little part explaining partial derivatives, so it just jumped to the part about differentials without any explanations.

Comment: That's by Leonard Susskind right, from his online lectures I thought he was quite a good teacher - are you using those too?

Comment: Yes, he is a great lecturer. I'm the problem.